# Where to find/Location of Firefox Extension Data (other than profileName/browser-extension-data)

Tags: firefox-addon

I wish to find data inserted into a Mozilla Firefox extension ["Hide Spoilers!"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-spoilers/). It contains words onto which spoiler shadow is cast.

Some of my other extension inserted-data can be found at:

```
C:\Users\[ME]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[PROFILE.NAME]\browser-extension-data
```

Therefore, the data's stored in *storage.js* file

The data usually consists of key-words and phrases (namely, in one of my other extensions that also serves a similar anti-spoiler fashion).

This extension, however, stores such data in another fashion.
I'm sure of that being true because, after manually moving out the extension file from

C:\Users[ME]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles[PROFILE.NAME]\extensions

and after reinstalling the extension at *addons.mozila* , the aforementioned inserted-data persisted.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it's the moz-extension+++ folders in the storage folder in your profile folder:

`C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile]\storage\default`

You can generate a list of UUIDs belonging to each of your extensions by pasting that into your browser's address bar:

`about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox`

Those UUIDs should match up with the folders to determine which folder belongs to which extension.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answer of @Arindrew: I needed an addon for my secondary PC's Firefox that's no longer available for download from the Mozilla addon site.
Since I still had the addon installed on my primary PC I found the addon's .XPI file at

`C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile]\extensions`

Copied that XPI file over to some folder on my secondary machine and within Firefox:

- Add-ons and themes
- Cog menu on the upper right
- Install Add-on from File...

In my particular case the filename of the Add-on was also just some UUID. `about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox` also helped me out on that point.